# comparing text while ignoring hidden characters? (bidirectional characters specifically)

Tags: java, scala

Our code does a lot of text comparison, and we're starting to note that some of our user-defined input has bidirectional formatting characters in it (sometimes needed, sometimes not). This is causing a lot of missed matches. For example:

"Some\u200eText\202cHere"
Looks identical to "SomeTextHere" but a string comparison returns false.

Is there a way to compare strings, but specifically tell the comparer to ignore hidden characters like this?

Comment: You can remove all the character you want to ignore before doing the comparison, or write your own comparison to skip those letters.

Comment: what all bidirectional element you are getting? is it something like â€Ž or the way you have stated in you question? do you have any common elements which you can replace with blank value ? check those replace them like str.replaceAll("\u200e", "");